# Load PDF inside a Bootstrap Accordion

Tags: object, pdf, iframe

I have been trying to load some PDFS that will show inside a Bootstrap accordion. The problem is that they load in a lot of different ways depending on the browser. I've been trying iframe and object html tags with different results and i have a huge flow in Safari where the accordion functionality breaks completely when i embed a PDF inside a panel.

So i guess my question is: Is there any sort of standard regarding crossbrowsing in order to make embeded PDF'S work in Chrome, Safari, IE11 and Firefox ?

Since i need this to work on mobile the situation is even worst. Some advice will be really appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at PDF.js. It will render PDF without using the built-in PDF viewers or browser plugins. It's the only way I've found to get PDF to render consistently... if not perfectly... in the major browsers. I didn't add this as an answer because it may not actually work for your particular PDF files.

Comment: I will give it a try (looks kinda complicated to implement tho) but any specific reason why you think PDF.js won't work for my specific situation ? Thanks ! @joelgeraci

Comment: PDF.js doesn't implement the full PDF specification. It works on most stuff really well but if you use certain transparency modes or other advanced color stuff, you may not get the same results as you'd get from Adobe Reader. And PDF.js is super simple really. A URL like this will do the trick.... http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf

Comment: Thanks @joelgeraci i was just trying to understand the way to integrate this in my app, do i just have to add the .js file in my html and then do the call, i'm gettin the pdf src from a json doc. Again many thanks for your feedback !

Comment: Yes - That's pretty much all you need to do. Take a look at their Viewer examples.

Comment: Hey @joelgeraci i have been dealing with pdf.js for a while and im not capable of making it work, id REALLY appreciate any help.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a canvas element with the class "panel-body" and give it an id of your choosing. Then add the following code to your document ready event.

```
PDFJS.getDocument('YOURPDF.pdf').then(function(pdf) {
    pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
        var scale = 1;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
        var canvas = document.getElementById('pdfOne'); // The id of your canvas
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        var renderContext = {
          canvasContext: context,
          viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
    });
});
```

That will get the first page rendered. You'll need to create buttons to let the user navigate through the document but it should be easy enough to get that working based on what I've provided and the samples.